# What's the difference between the two arpeggio symbols (default and upwards)?

Tags: piano, notation, arpeggios, ornaments

[image: Arpeggio symbols]

What is the difference between the symbol in the upper-left corner (with no arrow) and the one next to it (with an upwards arrow)? Aren't the two the same?

Comment: That diagram looks like it came right out of Musescore.

Comment: That could be possible. That was one of the first images I saw on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two both mean to roll upwards. The third means roll downwards. The second is often used when the third is used to make it direction clear.

Comment: I really like the terminology you used, "to ROLL upwards/downwards". Sounds very majestic!